# Input array into GUI Jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, append, jtextarea

Been trying to add my array, year and size of a house into a GUI, more precisely JTextarea. What's the simplest way of doing so? Not quite grasped data input yet.

```
public class House {
private int year;
private int size;
private static int nbrOfHouses;
public static final int MIN_SIZE = 10;

public House(int year, int size) {
    this.year = year;
    this.size = size;
}

public static int getNbrHouses() {
    return nbrOfHouses;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}
}



House[] myHouse = new House[10];{
  myHouse[0] = new House(1902, 120);
  myHouse[1] = new House(1954, 180);
  myHouse[2] = new House(1995,90);

  for(int i=0; i< myHouse.length; i++){
        if(myHouse[i]!=null){
          System.out.println(myHouse[i].getSize());

    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Write a formatter that converts the array of houses into a string and set it using the convenience method JTextArea.setText() or the model model JTextArea.getDocument().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTextArea` has a simple [`append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) method that should make it easy to append the results

For example...

```
for(int i=0; i< myHouse.length; i++){
    if(myHouse[i]!=null){
        textArea.append("Year: ");
        textArea.append(Integer.toString(myHouse[i].getYear()));
        textArea.append(".  Size: ");
        textArea.append(Integer.toString(myHouse[i].getSize()));
        textArea.append("\n");
    }
}
```

Take a look at [How to use text areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more deatils

Comment: Any idea why it puts the houses in three different textareas?

Comment: In your code, no idea, because you've not presented any example using a `JTextArea`